# HOW to show picklist value without clicking a button

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

```
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:selectList value="{!countries}"  size="1" onclick="submitform();">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectList><p/>
 
        <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>
    </apex:form>
 
    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
         <p>You have selected: {!countries}</p>
        
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public class sampleCon {
public string countries{get;set;}
    
        
    public PageReference test() {
        return null;
    }
        
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));
        return options;
    }
        
   
}
```

Comment: P.S. If you meant this to be a [Self-Answered Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), you can do this, but you should format the question and answer correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to submit the form manually, just add an apex:actionSupport.

```
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:selectList value="{!countries}"  size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="out" />
        </apex:selectList><p/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
         <p>You have selected: {!countries}</p>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```